# Using JavaScript utilize "Back to Top"

Tags: javascript

I found a "Back to Top" effect written in JavaScript. But there's something in the code I don't understand.Thanks a lot!

```
window.onload = function () {
    var oBtn = document.getElementById('btn1');
    var timer=null;

    oBtn.onclick= function () {
       timer=setInterval(function () {
            var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrolltop || document.body.scrollTop;
            var iSpeed = Math.floor(-scrollTop/8);//what does this mean?
           if(scrollTop===0)
           {
               clearInterval(timer);
           }

            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop + iSpeed;
        }, 30);
    };
};
```

Comment: There's a comment inline in the code saying "what does this mean?"

Comment: You should say that in your question to be more clear. Most people who understand the code wont read the comments as they already understand what the code is going to do.

Comment: make sure to camelcase like `scrollTop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iSpeed` is best thought of as a velocity.  As the document scrolls back upwards, it gets set to that velocity which gradually becomes smaller as it gets closer to the targeted element.

`Math.floor(-scrollTop/8)`
In this case, you're constantly scrolling up an 1/8th of the distance between your position and that element.

Comment: So this means, each time the scrollTop minus 1/ 8th of the itself until it equals 0?

Answer (score 1):

`-scrollTop` means `0-scrollTop`.

`-scrollTop/8` means `0-scrollTop` divided by 8.

`Math.floor()` rounds down to the nearest whole number.